# how to train and test a regression model

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I have to do my first assignment to multiple linear regression in R. I have two datasets. A training dataset and a testing dataset. I have made a model(logmodel with Multiple R-squared:  0.7904, which unfortunately doesn't satisfy the normality and homoscedasticity) and the aim is to predict the total rentals for bikes(the 18th column in the 2 datasets). Here is my model:

```
model <- lm(formula = cnt ~ yr + hr + weathersit + temp + hum, data = databikecleaned)
w <- 1/(lm(abs(model$residuals)~model$fitted.values)$fitted.values^2) 
logmodel <- lm(formula = log(cnt) ~ yr + hr + weathersit + temp + hum + I(hum^2) + I(temp^2) ,weight = w, data = databikecleaned)
```

How can I do it and how to test if the predictions that my model makes are good? I am a beginner that's why I may have silly questions.
I try this function but an error occurs

```
predict <- predict(logmodel,test_data)
```

"Error in hum^2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

```
rmse(predict, test_data[,18])
```

Comment: To get great answers quickly, make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Which function causes the error? `predict()` or `rmse`?

Comment: Could you provide your input data `databikecleaned` with `dput`? Possibly its some missing value/NA value in the `hum`-column. Also, it makes your question reproducible.

Comment: How can I to make my question reproducible? In predict() the error is occured, of course rmse doesn't run either due to the error in predict. Is there another way to make a prediction from my logmodel to the values of the 18th column in the 2nd datasets(test dataset)?